# Android Spotlight Always on Corner point

Tags: java, android

same the sample
but in my project , spotlight always show in corner
what should i do ?
or any offer for this same library?

here is my code

```
    View one = findViewById(R.id.img_drawer);
        int[] oneLocation = new int[2];
        one.getLocationInWindow(oneLocation);
        float oneX = oneLocation[0] + one.getWidth() / 2f;
        float oneY = oneLocation[1] + one.getHeight() / 2f;
        // make an target
        SimpleTarget firstTarget = new SimpleTarget.Builder(TripActivity.this).setPoint(oneX, oneY)
                .setRadius(100f)
                .setTitle("first title")
                .setDescription("first description")
                .build();
Spotlight.with(TripActivity.this)
                .setDuration(1000L)
                .setAnimation(new DecelerateInterpolator(2f))
                .setTargets(firstTarget)
                .setOnSpotlightStartedListener(new OnSpotlightStartedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStarted() {
                        Toast.makeText(TripActivity.this, "spotlight is started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                })
                .setOnSpotlightEndedListener(new OnSpotlightEndedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEnded() {
                        Toast.makeText(TripActivity.this, "spotlight is ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .start();
```

and pictures
[image: picture one]

[image: picture two]

Comment: Have you copied and pasted a code snippet from somewhere into your project?

Comment: first i write code , its not work
after i copy from this sample 
but i think this library not work for my xml code
because i change item position programmatically

Comment: Even if you change item position programmatically, the library should work fine if the position is correct. The problem might be due to the `getHeight()`/`getWidth()` functions returning 0, as your spotlight origin seems to be the top left corner of the screen. Try logging the output of these methods.

Comment: you are using fragment or activity?
i am also using same Library

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your spotlight target is getting created before the target view is actually inflated and created. To overcome this issue, you must create your spotlight target only once the view is inflated.

```
View one = findViewById(R.id.img_drawer);
int[] oneLocation = new int[2];
one.getLocationInWindow(oneLocation);
float oneX = oneLocation[0] + one.getWidth() / 2f;
float oneY = oneLocation[1] + one.getHeight() / 2f;
```

so in above code sample, oneX and oneY is coming as 0 and so your spotlight target is moving to top-left corner and only a quarter is visible.

Make use of post method, which can be called from any view. Post method takes a runnable thread and makes sure that everything in this post runnable is executed once the view is properly inflated.

```
// create globally
SimpleTarget firstTarget = null;

// do this in onCreate of Activity or in onCreateView of Fragment
View one = findViewById(R.id.img_drawer);

one.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        int[] oneLocation = new int[2];
        one.getLocationInWindow(oneLocation);
        float oneX = oneLocation[0] + one.getWidth() / 2f;
        float oneY = oneLocation[1] + one.getHeight() / 2f;

        // make a target
        firstTarget = new SimpleTarget.Builder(TripActivity.this)
            .setPoint(oneX, oneY)
            .setRadius(100f)
            .setTitle("first title")
            .setDescription("first description")
            .build();
    }
});

// Do this in onStart of Activity or in onViewCreated of Fragment
if (firstTarget != null)
    Spotlight.with(TripActivity.this)
        .setDuration(1000L)
        .setAnimation(new DecelerateInterpolator(2f))
        .setTargets(firstTarget)
        .setOnSpotlightStartedListener(new OnSpotlightStartedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStarted() {
                Toast.makeText(TripActivity.this, "spotlight is started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .setOnSpotlightEndedListener(new OnSpotlightEndedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEnded() {
                Toast.makeText(TripActivity.this, "spotlight is ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view was not ready yet, You have to call it in `doOnPreDraw` (I'm using core-ktx lib)

```
 binding.root.doOnPreDraw {
        showSpotlight() // call it here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is the view (element which you want to highlight) is not yet drawn into your root layout and you are trying to add spotlight on that.

The solution is below which solved my problem.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override public void onGlobalLayout() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget.Builder(activity)
                .setPoint(view)
                .setRadius(radius)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setDescription(description)
                .build();

        Spotlight.with(activity)
                .setDuration(500L)
                .setDuration(500L)
                .setAnimation(new DecelerateInterpolator(1f))
                .setTargets(target)
                .setOnSpotlightStartedListener(new OnSpotlightStartedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStarted() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnSpotlightEndedListener(new OnSpotlightEndedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEnded() {
                        App.getLocalStorage().write(sharedPrefKey, true);
                    }
                })
                .start();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your root layout from your xml file then

```
rootlayout.post { 
    //write your code for creating targets and spotlight 
}
```